# How to align pdf using pypdf

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, pypdf

I am extracting data from PDFs using pypdf (latest 2023).  All the documents are digital, but some of the forms seem slightly misaligned. This throws off my `page.extract_text()` method which uses bounding boxes to extract the fields.

How would you assess the documents are misaligned and transform and scale the documents to match a reference template using pypdf? So that is two asks, one to read the document and check alignment, and two how do I transform and scale the entire document to match the reference template. I don't think machine learning is necessary, but I am not sure. I also do not know the reason why the forms are misaligned; I assume there must be multiple templates floating about (I work in a large city government), or maybe when they are "printed" to PDF there are slight differences. I am not sure if I have the ability to force business to use a modified or marked version of the form that would help with alignment, so worst case scenario I would use existing landmarks in the form itself, rather than modifying the document.

Comment: I think my pdfs have other problems beyond misalligned text boxes. If it was just the text boxes I could adjust them to make them bigger to encompass both pdfs.